# TestCase() in C#- problem with DateTime argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Hey I wrote a test in C# which as argument takes only one DateTime argument. What I would like to do is to add `[TestCase(new DateTime(2022, 1, 31))]` above my test but when I try to do that I get an error that "An attribute must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type". What can I do?

Comment: For what it's worth, VB (aka VB.NET) provides literal DateTimes.  C# does not.

Comment: Just pass in a string `"2022-01-31"`. NUnit is smart enough to parse it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any use of `new` in the argument list to `TestCaseAttribute` will get you the same error. Because of the restrictions that C# imposes, NUnit provides `TestCaseSourceAttribute`.

However, `TestCaseSourceAttribute` involves more typing and in this case, you can provide a string as the argument. Note that the argument to the test method should still be typed as a DateTime even though you are providing a string. As noted in one of the comments, NUnit is smart enough to convert it.

```
[TestCase("2022/1/31")]
public void MyTestMethod(DateTime dt)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple test this is the solution
[Nunit documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html). If you don't have multiple parameters to test has few sense to pass value from outside you can define a variable inside the test

```
private static DateTime[] source = new DateTime[]
{
    new DateTime(2021,1,12),
    new DateTime(2022,2,12),
    new DateTime(1988,4,4)
};

[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(source))]
public void XXX(DateTime dt)
{
             
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*BTW. There is a new type `DateOnly` available now in .NET. *

The most trivial case can be solved by using simpler inputs:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(2022, 1, 31)]
public void Test(int year, int month, int day)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(31, new DateOnly(year, month, day));
}
```

However, `DynamicData` offers the most flexibility:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestCases()
{
    var testCases = new List<TestCase>()
    {
        new TestCase()
        {
            DT = new DateOnly(2022, 1, 31),
            ExpectedDay = 31
        },
    };

    return testCases
#if DEBUG //protect from a bad checkin by running all test cases in RELEASE builds
            //.Where(tc => tc.Name.Contains("..."))
#endif
        .Select(tc => new object[] { tc });
}

[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetTestCases), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void Test(TestCase tc)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(tc.ExpectedDay, tc.DT.Day);
}

public class TestCase
{
    public DateOnly DT { get; init; }

    public int ExpectedDay { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: Question is about NUnit. Your answer is about MsTest.

Answer (score -2):

Suggest using either `MemberData` property as described in [this blog post](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/) or replacing it with `TheoryData` as described [here](https://hamidmosalla.com/2020/04/05/xunit-part-8-using-theorydata-instead-of-memberdata-and-classdata/).

Arguments passed to tests must be constants, but you can use either of the above fields to work around that requirement.

Comment: Link only answers... should have been a comment.

Comment: this is for xunit - the OP is asking for nunit